# How do I write the SQL code to generate a 4-level JSON output?

Tags: sql, json, group-by, multi-level

I'm trying to create a 4-level json. What is messing me up is the "skus" level here. I'm trying to create a groups level, then a skus level, a fieldInfo level and within that all the field values etc for all the skus in a given group.

Here is a sample of my data:

| SKU | FieldGroup | GroupSort | FieldName | FieldSort | GroupBackgroundColor | LabelName | DefaultValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RB130-9-H-S21D2-PID-OS | Compliance | 9 | item_volume_unit_of_measure | 246 | CC9999 | item_volume_unit_of_measure |  |
| RB130-9-H-S21D2-PID-OS | Product Enrichment | 6 | leg_style | 172 | BBA680 | Leg Style |  |
| RB130-9-H-S21D2-PID-OS | Basic | 4 | apparel_size_class | 56 | F8A45E | Apparel Size Class |  |
| RB130-9-H-S21D2-PID-OS | Basic | 4 | shirt_size_class | 51 | F8A45E | Shirt Size Class |  |
| RB130-9-H-S21D2-PID-OS | Dimensions | 7 | item_height | 198 | 8DB4E2 | Item Height |  |
| RB130-9-H-S21D2-PID-OS | Variation | 3 | parent_sku | 43 | FF8080 | Parent SKU |  |
| RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS | Variation | 3 | parent_sku | 43 | FF8080 | Parent SKU |  |
| RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS | Dimensions | 7 | item_height | 198 | 8DB4E2 | Item Height |  |
| RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS | Basic | 4 | shirt_size_class | 51 | F8A45E | Shirt Size Class |  |
| RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS | Basic | 4 | apparel_size_class | 56 | F8A45E | Apparel Size Class |  |
| RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS | Product Enrichment | 6 | leg_style | 172 | BBA680 | Leg Style |  |
| RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS | Compliance | 9 | item_volume_unit_of_measure | 246 | CC9999 | item_volume_unit_of_measure |  |

What I'm trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
{
    "groups": [{
        "group": "Group1",
        "skus": [{
            "sku": "xxx",
            "fieldInfo": [{
                "fieldName": "field1",
                "value": "1"
            }, {
                "fieldName": "2",
                "fieldValue": "2"
            }]
        }, {
            "sku": "yyy",
            "fieldInfo": [{
                "fieldName": "field1",
                "value": "1"
            }, {
                "fieldName": "2",
                "fieldValue": "2"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "group": "Group2",
        "skus": [{
            "sku": "xxx",
            "fieldInfo": [{
                "fieldName": "field1",
                "value": "1"
            }, {
                "fieldName": "2",
                "fieldValue": "2"
            }]
        }, {
            "sku": "yyy",
            "fieldInfo": [{
                "fieldName": "field1",
                "value": "1"
            }, {
                "fieldName": "2",
                "fieldValue": "2"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "group": "Group3",
        "skus": [{
            "sku": "xxx",
            "fieldInfo": [{
                "fieldName": "field1",
                "value": "1"
            }, {
                "fieldName": "2",
                "fieldValue": "2"
            }]
        }, {
            "sku": "yyy",
            "fieldInfo": [{
                "fieldName": "field1",
                "value": "1"
            }, {
                "fieldName": "2",
                "fieldValue": "2"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

My code so far:

```
select (

select fieldGroup,  max(groupbackgroundcolor) backgroundcolor,JSON_Query(max(skuinfo.skus)) skuinfo
    from Amazon.AmazonSpreadsheetData sd
    cross apply (
            select (select sd2.sku, JSON_Query(max(fieldinfo.fields)) fieldInfo from Amazon.AmazonSpreadsheetData sd2
                cross apply (
                        select (select fieldid, FieldName,LabelName,DefaultValue 
                        from Amazon.AmazonSpreadsheetData sd3
                        where sd3.sku=sd2.sku
                            and sd3.fieldgroup=sd2.fieldgroup
                            and sd3.collectionid=sd2.collectionid
                            and sd3.deliveryDate=sd2.deliverydate
                            and sd3. TemplateName=sd2.templatename
                            and sd3.productType=sd2.producttype
                        order by sd3.parentchildsort, sd3.fieldSort for JSON path ) fields               
                ) fieldInfo
            where sd2.fieldgroup=sd.fieldgroup 
                and sd2.sku=sd.sku 
                and sd2.collectionid=sd.collectionid
                and sd2.deliveryDate=sd.deliverydate
                and sd2.TemplateName=sd.templatename
                and sd2.productType=sd.producttype
            group by sd2.sku
            order by max(sd2.parentchildsort), sd2.sku 
            for JSON path )skus
            --order by parentchildsort,sd.sku for JSON path
            ) skuInfo

    where collectionid=524
        and sd.deliveryDate='2021-02-15'
        and sd.TemplateName='Boys'
        and sd.productType='pants'
        and sd.sku like '%RB130-9-%'
    group by fieldgroup
    --order by max(groupsort)
    for JSON path, root('Groups') 
) jstring
```

But all that does is gets the max sku for each group:

```
{
"Groups": [{
    "fieldGroup": "Basic",
    "backgroundcolor": "F8A45E",
    "skuinfo": [{
        "sku": "RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS",
        "fieldInfo": [{
            "fieldid": 220702,
            "FieldName": "update_delete",
            "LabelName": "Update Delete",
            "DefaultValue": "Update"
        }, {
            "fieldid": 221206,
            "FieldName": "product_description",
            "LabelName": "Product Description",
            "DefaultValue": "descrip"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "fieldGroup": "Compliance",
    "backgroundcolor": "CC9999",
    "skuinfo": [{
        "sku": "RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS",
        "fieldInfo": [{
            "fieldid": 221390,
            "FieldName": "fabric_type",
            "LabelName": "Fabric Type",
            "DefaultValue": ""
        }, {
            "fieldid": 220742,
            "FieldName": "import_designation",
            "LabelName": "Import Designation",
            "DefaultValue": ""
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "fieldGroup": "Dimensions",
    "backgroundcolor": "8DB4E2",
    "skuinfo": [{
        "sku": "RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS",
        "fieldInfo": [{
            "fieldid": 221478,
            "FieldName": "chest_size",
            "LabelName": "Chest Size",
            "DefaultValue": ""
        }, {
            "fieldid": 220930,
            "FieldName": "chest_size_unit_of_measure",
            "LabelName": "Chest Size Unit Of Measure",
            "DefaultValue": ""
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "fieldGroup": "Discovery",
    "backgroundcolor": "92D050",
    "skuinfo": [{
        "sku": "RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS",
        "fieldInfo": [{
            "fieldid": 220842,
            "FieldName": "bullet_point1",
            "LabelName": "Key Product Features",
            "DefaultValue": ""
        }, {
            "fieldid": 221502,
            "FieldName": "bullet_point2",
            "LabelName": "Key Product Features",
            "DefaultValue": ""
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "fieldGroup": "Fulfillment",
    "backgroundcolor": "B7DEE8",
    "skuinfo": [{
        "sku": "RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS",
        "fieldInfo": [{
            "fieldid": 221190,
            "FieldName": "fulfillment_center_id",
            "LabelName": "Fulfillment Center ID",
            "DefaultValue": "DEFAULT"
        }, {
            "fieldid": 221422,
            "FieldName": "package_height",
            "LabelName": "Package Height",
            "DefaultValue": ""
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "fieldGroup": "Images",
    "backgroundcolor": "FFFF00",
    "skuinfo": [{
        "sku": "RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS",
        "fieldInfo": [{
            "fieldid": 221358,
            "FieldName": "other_image_url1",
            "LabelName": "Other Image URL1",
            "DefaultValue": ""
        }, {
            "fieldid": 220858,
            "FieldName": "other_image_url2",
            "LabelName": "Other Image URL2",
            "DefaultValue": ""
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "fieldGroup": "Offer",
    "backgroundcolor": "FF0000",
    "skuinfo": [{
        "sku": "RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS",
        "fieldInfo": [{
            "fieldid": 221014,
            "FieldName": "list_price",
            "LabelName": "Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price",
            "DefaultValue": ""
        }, {
            "fieldid": 221414,
            "FieldName": "map_price",
            "LabelName": "Minimum Advertised Price",
            "DefaultValue": ""
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "fieldGroup": "Product Enrichment",
    "backgroundcolor": "BBA680",
    "skuinfo": [{
        "sku": "RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS",
        "fieldInfo": [{
            "fieldid": 221398,
            "FieldName": "bottom_style",
            "LabelName": "Bottom Style",
            "DefaultValue": ""
        }, {
            "fieldid": 220798,
            "FieldName": "subject_character",
            "LabelName": "character",
            "DefaultValue": ""
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "fieldGroup": "Required",
    "backgroundcolor": "FCD5B4",
    "skuinfo": [{
        "sku": "RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS",
        "fieldInfo": [{
            "fieldid": 221418,
            "FieldName": "feed_product_type",
            "LabelName": "Product Type",
            "DefaultValue": "pants"
        }, {
            "fieldid": 220758,
            "FieldName": "item_sku",
            "LabelName": "Seller SKU",
            "DefaultValue": "KP-RB130-9-S21D2"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "fieldGroup": "Variation",
    "backgroundcolor": "FF8080",
    "skuinfo": [{
        "sku": "RB130-9-H-S21D2-SSKC-OS",
        "fieldInfo": [{
            "fieldid": 220934,
            "FieldName": "parent_child",
            "LabelName": "Parentage",
            "DefaultValue": "Parent"
        }, {
            "fieldid": 221538,
            "FieldName": "parent_sku",
            "LabelName": "Parent SKU",
            "DefaultValue": ""
        }, {
            "fieldid": 221234,
            "FieldName": "relationship_type",
            "LabelName": "Relationship Type",
            "DefaultValue": "Variation"
        }, {
            "fieldid": 221030,
            "FieldName": "variation_theme",
            "LabelName": "Variation Theme",
            "DefaultValue": "SizeColor"
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

I'm missing a step or a group by or something.

Thank you.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and JSON support is very product specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I'm guessing it's Microsoft SQL Server, by the use of `CROSS APPLY`. Please tag questions about Microsoft SQL Server with [tag:sql-server], not just [tag:sql]. The best reason to tag your question accurately is that you will attract the right set of Stack Overflow users who can give you the best answer to your question.

Comment: Bill, you are correct. And I'd like to edit the tags but...when I try to edit the question to add the new tag, I'm now getting an error that one or more of the code block is not indented properly.